# delphi: how to trap/remove all error messages?

Tags: delphi

My Delphi project uses a `Twebbrowser`

Sometimes (I could not determine when), I got a message error

```
‘Could not obtain OLE control window handle’
```

Is there an easy way to remove all these error messages ?
Like a global error handler.

My goal is not to solve the problem, simply prevent that error message from being displayed.

Comment: *My goal is not to solve the problem.* Why not? It should be quite tractable.

Comment: The following might help :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351714/ole-control-window-handle-error-with-webbrowser-and-delphi-2007

Comment: IMHO, _My goal is not to solve the problem._ is just the wrong attitude.